# Programatically Add entry in custom table when from admin panel user is created

Tags: user

I want when from admin panel user is created then entry also inserted into my custom table. I want this information in my table which consists following structure User_id,full_name_email. Where i write insert query for my requirement.

Comment: are you creating the module or you want the core hack?

Comment: Wouldn't suggest a "core hack"! - you know he's watching...

Comment: How we can do it with module.

Comment: you can use observer for this adminhtml_customer_save_after event it will give customer data.

Comment: Can you provide full procedure, i access saveAction in the customer controller i am new in magento.

Comment: Admin user or customer? What do you have? Does the custom table already exist?

Answer (score 1):

In your controller action

```
$mymodel = Mage::getModel('mymodel/mymodel');

//post field id# user_id
$mymodel->setUserId($this->getRequest()->getPost('user_id'));

//post field id# full_name_email
$mymodel->setFullNameEmail($this->getRequest()->getPost('full_name_email'));

//save data
$mymodel->save();
```

Your question is very vague in terms of information but this is the general way to save form post data to the database tables in magento..